# Which node reads the configuration file?

Tags: actuator, nxt, yaml, nxt-ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with NXT-ROS. To define the sensors and actuators, you need to create a robot.yaml file. My question is, how is this file used? Is it read by some other node? By which?

I think it might be the node nxt_ros, but i am not really sure.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206054/which-node-reads-the-configuration-file?/) by [mikelom](https://answers.ros.org/users/21530/mikelom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct as per the tutorial:

`<node pkg="nxt_ros" type="nxt_ros.py" name="nxt_ros" output="screen" respawn="true"> <rosparam command="load" file="$(find learning_nxt)/robot.yaml" /> </node>`

This launch file XML takes the robot.yaml file and loads the values to the ROS parameter server. It does this using the `<rosparam>` tags. Since it is nested in the `<node>` tags it sets all the parameters as private names under the nxt_ros node.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2